# Convert MsWord first page to Image

Tags: c#, image, com, ms-word

I have an msword document that consists of some pages, i need convert only the first page to image and save it. Each page can consist of images, tables, text, etc. But i can't use clipboard buffer or any commercial software.

May be anybody know some other ways ?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on the "Generate thumbnail for Document" option and word will generate an image for you (that Windows 7 uses to show the large icon view of the document.

In word 2010, click File-Info

then the Properties Drop down
Then Advanced properties
Then Summary tab
and finally SHOW PREVIEW PICTURE

And what's worse, you can't automate it! Ugh, Something about a security risk.

When you do that, there will be an extra WMF file embedded within the DOCX that you can extract.

Comment: I can't use this feature, because it require user manually to save thumbnail and we can't automate it.

Answer (score 0):

Print your first page to the [Microsoft Office Document Image Writer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/save-an-office-document-as-a-tiff-file-HP001027858.aspx).

It will give you a TIFF image.

---

**EDIT**

Alternatively, print to the [Microsoft XPS Document Writer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145058.aspx) and then [convert XPS to an image](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/xps2img-converts-xps-into-image).

Comment: It will create monochrone image, but i need colorfull.